# Debug VB6 COM-object used in classic ASP page in VS2015

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, vb6

I have a bug in a method of VB6 COM object. It is used in my web-application (mix of classic ASP with newer ASP.NET, Visual Studio 2015) in classic ASP page in the form "OBJECT RUNAT=server PROGID=fgcom id=bla VIEWASTEXT>/OBJECT". I have a code for everything, VB6 IDE including, ISS is 7.5 (win 7).

Can I debug into the COM object? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug in the VB6 IDE a com component.

In fact what you do is open the project in the VB6 IDE put a break point on the first executable line in the sub or function that has the error, then start the component in the IDE, then run the app that consumes it to the point of the call to the VB6 component method. At that point the VB6 IDE will flash if minimised and you will see the focus on the break point and you can use the step and watch functions in the IDE.  This assumes that you have the IDE on the same computer as the calling code which is the easiest case.

Notes

1. I recommend that you vary the name of the class temporarily during debugging for time-efficiency because if your component is already in memory already then IT may receive the calls from your calling code. So if your code instantiates MyComponent.SomeClass then change to MyComponent.SomeClassA in VB6 and your calling code for the period of the debugging effort, then reset for final compile after you find the solution. You can flush the in-memory version via reboots and such but it's easier and more definite if you switch the class name.
2. To be absolutely sure your debug version of the component is being called put a break point on the initialisation sub of the component.

Once set up it is a really easy, repeatable and efficient process.

Let me now if you are not familiar with where to change those settings etc.

Comment: If they are using late binding (CreateObject) the name changing should work fine. But if it is early binding (compile-time references) this will cause additional complications. References will have to be created...

Comment: @DaveInCaz Yeah I figure there are a few complications but I didn't want to scare the OP off as it is completely do-able if he has control of all the source. But good point. Lets see.

Comment: I was able to debug your way, no name changes, went smooth (late binding, yes). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Paul, glad to be of help. If my answer was 'correct' then please click the tick mark on the left of it to mark it as useful. Also, if you overcame any significant issues  or any points to note then please edit into your question for benefit of future users.